# C compiler cannot create executables (cygwin, rtorrent, windows)

Tags: cygwin

I was following "[rTorrent on Windows](http://rtwi.jmk.hu/wiki/rTorrentOnWindows)" tutorial, and i think i installed all requested packages for rTorrent, though i am not 100% sure.

Problem starts with installing and configuring libsigc++

**./configure**

> user@computer ~
> $ cd /usr/local/src/libsigc++-2.2.10
>
> user@computer /usr/local/src/libsigc++-2.2.10
>
> $ ./configure
>
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>
> checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
>
> checking for gawk... gawk
>
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>
> checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
>
> checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
>
> checking whether make supports GNU make features... yes
>
> checking for g++... no
>
> checking for c++... no
>
> checking for gpp... no
>
> checking for aCC... no
>
> checking for CC... no
>
> checking for cxx... no
>
> checking for cc++... no
>
> checking for cl.exe... no
>
> checking for FCC... no
>
> checking for KCC... no
>
> checking for RCC... no
>
> checking for xlC_r... no
>
> checking for xlC... no
>
> checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
>
> configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/libsigc++-2.2.10':
>
> configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
>
> See `config.log' for more details

config.log: http://pastebin.com/G1Xn30iL

Did i miss any package or something else?
I am hoping for help. This is my first time with cygwin and rtorrent... obviously i need to figure things out before going further :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a C compiler in your cygwin environment.  Run the cygwin setup again and choose to install g++, and you should see progress.